# How to pass variable value to a python file from robotframework file?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

**Python file**
*test.py*

```
sysman_auth = (username,password)
```

**Robot file**
*sample.robot*

```
*** Variables ***
${uname}     testuser
${password}   testpassword
```

How do I pass *testuser* and *testpassword* from sample.robot file to test.py file?

Comment: I saw the other way - taking from python to robotframework. I am not sure what is your intention in taking a variable from RF to python, since you can write your tests in RF itself (if you have written your keywords and code in RF), or you if you want python, you may use pytest instead of RF entirely.
Anyway, this link may be of help to you. Check this. [RobotFramework official forum](https://forum.robotframework.org/t/passing-a-python-variable-to-a-python-file-which-is-run-from-the-robot-file/1386)

Comment: how are you executing your python script? You could pass it to python as a command line argument.

Comment: @jii Janous can you please let me know how to pass it to python as a command-line argument? Here I want to execute a robot framework code that uses python library for test case reporting. I couldn't pass credentials to python code using --variables

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough details about how you are loading your python script. However, I would guess that what you asked simply isn't possible without some sort of trickery such as reading in the python script, modifying it, and writing it back out before you run it.

What *is* possible, however, is if you modify your python code to use environment variables. It's very easy for a robot script to set an environment variable.